# Hide/show ace:dialog from JSF managed bean

Tags: jsf, dialog, icefaces, managed-bean

I am having difficulty in trying to show an `<ace:dialog>` dialog from a backing bean class. I have tried to access the dialog box component through the following code:

```
context.getViewRoot().findComponent("allianceMemberForm:addAlliance:addAllianceForm:selectStartDate");
```

However, I do not know how to hide or show this dialog from within a bean method. How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute javascript method from server side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711409/how-to-execute-javascript-method-from-server-side)

Answer (score 1):

After some more experimentation I have managed to come up with two solutions.

1.Set a boolean value in my managed bean and attach this to this property to the visible attribute  of the ace:dialog component. Then I am able to toggle this boolean value using property action listeners.

2.Using javascript context:

```
JavaScriptRunner.runScript(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "ice.ace.instance('allianceMemberForm:addAlliance').show()");
```